# css buttons being below toolbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got this toolbar that has some buttons, and a sperator in between them, but for some reason when I add the separator the buttons become wonky.

This is a snippet showing the issue (srry for messy css code, but I use scss and the app.css is hughe, so just took some stuff to show what was needed)

```css
main #related {
  min-width: 200px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1; }
  main #related.ng-enter {
-webkit-animation: slideInLeft 1s;
-moz-animation: slideInLeft 1s;
-ms-animation: slideInLeft 1s;
animation: slideInLeft 1s; }
  main #related.ng-leave {
-webkit-animation: slideOutLeft 1s;
-moz-animation: slideOutLeft 1s;
-ms-animation: slideOutLeft 1s;
animation: slideOutLeft 1s; }
main #page-detail {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s; }
  main #page-detail #toolbar {
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
height: 56px;
margin: 0; }
main #page-detail #toolbar .btn, main #page-detail #toolbar .btn-large {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px; }
main #page-detail #toolbar .separator {
  height: 56px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }
  main #page-detail #content #editor {
padding: 20px 50px; }
main #page-detail #content #editor ul {
  list-style: initial;
  margin: initial;
  padding: 0 0 0 40px; }
main #page-detail #content #editor li {
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: disc; }

.row {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px; }
  .row:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both; }
  .row .col {
float: left;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0 0.75rem; }
.row .col.s1 {
  width: 8.33333%;
  margin-left: 0; }
.row .col.s2 {
  width: 16.66667%;
  margin-left: 0; }
.row .col.s3 {
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 0; }
.row .col.s4 {
  width: 33.33333%;
  margin-left: 0; }
.row .col.s5 {
  width: 41.66667%;
  margin-left: 0; }
.row .col.s6 {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 0; }
.row .col.s7 {
  width: 58.33333%;
  margin-left: 0; }
.row .col.s8 {
  width: 66.66667%;
  margin-left: 0; }
.row .col.s9 {
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 0; }
.row .col.s10 {
  width: 83.33333%;
  margin-left: 0; }
.row .col.s11 {
  width: 91.66667%;
  margin-left: 0; }
.row .col.s12 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0; }
.row .col.offset-s1 {
  margin-left: 8.33333%; }
.row .col.offset-s2 {
  margin-left: 16.66667%; }
.row .col.offset-s3 {
  margin-left: 25%; }
.row .col.offset-s4 {
  margin-left: 33.33333%; }
.row .col.offset-s5 {
  margin-left: 41.66667%; }
.row .col.offset-s6 {
  margin-left: 50%; }
.row .col.offset-s7 {
  margin-left: 58.33333%; }
.row .col.offset-s8 {
  margin-left: 66.66667%; }
.row .col.offset-s9 {
  margin-left: 75%; }
.row .col.offset-s10 {
  margin-left: 83.33333%; }
.row .col.offset-s11 {
  margin-left: 91.66667%; }
.row .col.offset-s12 {
  margin-left: 100%; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .row .col.m1 {
    width: 8.33333%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.m2 {
    width: 16.66667%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.m3 {
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.m4 {
    width: 33.33333%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.m5 {
    width: 41.66667%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.m6 {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.m7 {
    width: 58.33333%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.m8 {
    width: 66.66667%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.m9 {
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.m10 {
    width: 83.33333%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.m11 {
    width: 91.66667%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.m12 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.offset-m1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333%; }
  .row .col.offset-m2 {
    margin-left: 16.66667%; }
  .row .col.offset-m3 {
    margin-left: 25%; }
  .row .col.offset-m4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333%; }
  .row .col.offset-m5 {
    margin-left: 41.66667%; }
  .row .col.offset-m6 {
    margin-left: 50%; }
  .row .col.offset-m7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333%; }
  .row .col.offset-m8 {
    margin-left: 66.66667%; }
  .row .col.offset-m9 {
    margin-left: 75%; }
  .row .col.offset-m10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333%; }
  .row .col.offset-m11 {
    margin-left: 91.66667%; }
  .row .col.offset-m12 {
    margin-left: 100%; } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 993px) {
  .row .col.l1 {
    width: 8.33333%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.l2 {
    width: 16.66667%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.l3 {
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.l4 {
    width: 33.33333%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.l5 {
    width: 41.66667%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.l6 {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.l7 {
    width: 58.33333%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.l8 {
    width: 66.66667%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.l9 {
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.l10 {
    width: 83.33333%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.l11 {
    width: 91.66667%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.l12 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .row .col.offset-l1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333%; }
  .row .col.offset-l2 {
    margin-left: 16.66667%; }
  .row .col.offset-l3 {
    margin-left: 25%; }
  .row .col.offset-l4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333%; }
  .row .col.offset-l5 {
    margin-left: 41.66667%; }
  .row .col.offset-l6 {
    margin-left: 50%; }
  .row .col.offset-l7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333%; }
  .row .col.offset-l8 {
    margin-left: 66.66667%; }
  .row .col.offset-l9 {
    margin-left: 75%; }
  .row .col.offset-l10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333%; }
  .row .col.offset-l11 {
    margin-left: 91.66667%; }
  .row .col.offset-l12 {
    margin-left: 100%; } }

.btn, .btn-large, .btn-flat {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; }

.btn.disabled, .disabled.btn-large, .btn-floating.disabled, .btn-large.disabled, .btn:disabled, .btn-large:disabled, .btn-large:disabled, .btn-floating:disabled {
  background-color: #DFDFDF !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #9F9F9F !important;
  cursor: default; }
  .btn.disabled *, .disabled.btn-large *, .btn-floating.disabled *, .btn-large.disabled *, .btn:disabled *, .btn-large:disabled *, .btn-large:disabled *, .btn-floating:disabled * {
pointer-events: none; }
  .btn.disabled:hover, .disabled.btn-large:hover, .btn-floating.disabled:hover, .btn-large.disabled:hover, .btn:disabled:hover, .btn-large:disabled:hover, .btn-large:disabled:hover, .btn-floating:disabled:hover {
background-color: #DFDFDF;
color: #9F9F9F; }

.btn i, .btn-large i, .btn-floating i, .btn-large i, .btn-flat i {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  line-height: inherit; }

.btn, .btn-large {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #fb4400;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer; }
  .btn:hover, .btn-large:hover {
background-color: #ff5516; }

.btn-floating {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 37px;
  height: 37px;
  line-height: 37px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fb4400;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle; }
  .btn-floating i {
width: inherit;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
font-size: 1.6rem;
line-height: 37px; }
  .btn-floating:before {
border-radius: 0; }
  .btn-floating.btn-large {
width: 55.5px;
height: 55.5px; }
.btn-floating.btn-large i {
  line-height: 55.5px; }

button.btn-floating {
  border: none; }

.fixed-action-btn {
  position: fixed;
  right: 23px;
  bottom: 23px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 998; }
  .fixed-action-btn ul {
left: 0;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
bottom: 64px;
margin: 0; }
.fixed-action-btn ul li {
  margin-bottom: 15px; }
.fixed-action-btn ul a.btn-floating {
  opacity: 0; }

.btn-flat {
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #343434;
  cursor: pointer; }
  .btn-flat.disabled {
color: #b3b3b3;
cursor: default; }

.btn-large {
  height: 54px;
  line-height: 56px; }
  .btn-large i {
font-size: 1.6rem; }

.btn-block {
  display: block; }

.dropdown-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-height: 650px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  will-change: width, height; }
  .dropdown-content li {
clear: both;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
cursor: pointer;
line-height: 1.5rem;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
text-transform: none; }
.dropdown-content li:hover, .dropdown-content li.active {
  background-color: #eee; }
.dropdown-content li > a, .dropdown-content li > span {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #fb4400;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 1rem; }
.dropdown-content li > a > i {
  height: inherit;
  line-height: inherit; }

.black {
  background-color: #000000 !important; }

.black-text {
  color: #000000 !important; }

.white {
  background-color: #FFFFFF !important; }

.white-text {
  color: #FFFFFF !important; }

.transparent {
  background-color: transparent !important; }

.transparent-text {
  color: transparent !important; }
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="row">


    <div class="col s2 black white-text" id="related" ng-if="!hideRelated">
      <h4>Side bar</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col s12 m10 offset-m2" id="page-detail">

      <div class="row" id="toolbar">
        <a class="btn btn-flat"><i class="material-icons mdi-navigation-close"></i></a>
        <span class="separator"></span>
        <a class="btn">Edit</i></a>

      </div>
      <div class="row" id="content">

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: If you have similar problem, try to remove any and all unneeded code and see how much simple example you can get that is still broken. Usually while you remove the code, you will come to a part that - when removed - will fix it and that is where you should start looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your vertical align to anything except for baseline (which includes space between lines)

```
.separator { vertical-align:middle; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by wonky. You could change the CSS:

```
main #page-detail #toolbar .separator {
  /* height: 56px; */
  /* display: inline-block; */
  margin: 0 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wksL819n/

Comment: Wonkey is The part where The buttons are below the toolbar. But when you remove the seperator they are on the right position ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `display: inline-block;` from `main #page-detail #toolbar .separator`:

```
main #page-detail #toolbar .separator {
  height: 56px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }
```